# VIN Vehicle Identification Number, how to figure out the WMI part?

Tags: vin

I am trying to figure out how to breakdown a vehicle vin number.
There is an explanation of how a VIN is build (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number#Components_of_the_VIN) but it fails to explain what to do with manufacturers that only have 2 digits assigned instead of 3 digits.

If I understand correct what is written there then every VIN number must be 17 characters long, and the first 3 characters are the WMI (World Manufaturer Identification).

Then there is a list of WMI on the same page, but some manufacturers only have 2 characters in that list, not 3.
How to read such a VIN number ? Will it be only 16 characters long or how do I regognize that a WMI is 2 or 3 characters ?

for example nissan has WMI = JN which is only 2 characters.
2 VIN numbers for Nissan that I know that are valid are :
JN1UC4E26F9001391 and JNKCP0106TT541680
How can I know that for these 2 VIn numbers only the first 2 digits are to be read and used for the WMI ?

Answer (score 1):

In you examples it is in fact 3 characters that Set the WMI information

JN1UC4E26F9001391

NISSAN MOTOR COMPANY, LTD.  **JN1**,1N4 3995 RESEARCH PARK DRIVE        ANN ARBOR   MI  48104       PASSENGER CAR   SEE MEMO    7/29/1986

JNKCP0106TT541680

NISSAN RESEARCH & DEVELOPMENT   JN1,**JNK** 750 17TH STREET, N.W.       WASHINGTON  DC  20006       PASSENGER CAR   ALL 1/13/1992

1st character- Identifies the country in which the vehicle was manufactured.
For example: U.S.A.(1or 4), Canada(2), Mexico(3), Japan(J), Korea(K), England(S), Germany(W), Italy(Z)

2nd character- Identifies the manufacturer. For example; Audi(A),
BMW(B), Buick(4), Cadillac(6), Chevrolet(1), Chrysler(C), Dodge(B),
Ford(F), GM Canada(7), General Motors(G), Honda(H), Jaquar(A), Lincoln(L), Mercedes Benz(D), Mercury(M), Nissan(N), Oldsmobile(3), Pontiac(2or5), Plymouth(P), Saturn(8), Toyota(T), VW(V), Volvo(V).

3rd character- Identifies vehicle type or manufacturing division.

Per [VIN descriptor](http://www.vinguard.org/vin.htm)

This link contains the most current WMI information for all, this is were I got my data

[WMI for all manufactures](ftp://ftp.nhtsa.dot.gov/manufacture/)

In any Case it is not 3 or 2 for WMI it is

1 for country

2 for manufacturer

3 for type

this gets a little tricky because IF "2" = "N" that is not necessarily Nissan, for example  1N9 = NOMAD CUSTOM CYCLES INC.

Let me know if that helps or if you find a place to get VDS information

Comment: This tricky part is exact the problem I am trying to explain.
JN1 is nissan
JNK is nissan
1N9 is not nissan but nomad custom ...
The second char is not enough to know the manufacturer
You need a database that contains all possible combinations for the 3 first characters
The link you provide I already found, it is also not complete

Comment: its even worse with 2H because H should be Honda, but 2HM is Hyunday. So it seems that the second char alone is not enough to identifie the manufacturer

Comment: The link is incomplete ? it has over 36000 manufactures and if you match by first 3 Characters you should be able to find a match.  Give me an example of a VIN's WMI that is not in manufature.mdb.

basically you Must use the first 3 to ID a VIN the first 2 will never work

Comment: Are there over 36000 manufacturers ? I have all different combinations of the first 3 chars of this database and of others in my database, still we receive some vin's that are not found. I work for a company that carries new cars from manufacturers and loading/unloading places to other loading/unloading places or to dealers. We get hundreds of new vin's every day. Some manufactures send us updates of their vin database, some do not, there is our problem

Comment: here's another list that I used  http://www.autocalculator.org/VIN/WMI.aspx#.VcGxkfmDsTF

Comment: So there are 36000 listed many are subsidiaries of the same company.

The WMI information is required to be sent to the nhtsa are that Database is updated as they see fit and is public 

I have tried thousands of VIN's and I have not found one that can not be IDed by the information in that DB, you do have to massage the data a little to get rid of dups etc

The VDS data is the 4 th - 8th char and the manufactures get to "make that up" so they need to update you unless there is a common place for  that data.

Answer (score 0):

Your wiki page seems pretty clear that it's either a 3-character WMI, or a 2-character WMI followed by a 9.

Comment: It is also very clear that this is only for manufacturers with less than 500 cars per year, are you suggesting that nissan, mitisubusi, honda and other asian manufacturers are only producing 500 cars per year ?

Comment: In the list on that page nissan has wmi = JN,  but JN1UC4E26F9001391 is a valid vinnumber for a nissan car as also is JNKCP0106TT541680, They both do not have 9 at the 3th position

Comment: Now I understand your confusion.  You missed the line that says "For example, within 1G (assigned to General Motors in the United States), 1G1 represents Chevrolet passenger cars; 1G2, Pontiac passenger cars; and 1GC, Chevrolet trucks."  Nissan has all of the three-letter WMIs that start with JN.

Comment: That's what I thought to at first,
but for example Honda has WMI 2H
So, everything that starts with 2H is Honda right ?

what about 2HM which is Hyunday ? How does that fits in then ?

Answer (score 0):

There are an *abundance* of libraries out there, on GitHub and elsewhere, which are designed to decode VINs.  *"Do not do a thing already done."*

Comment: how to search on them ? I can't find them on github or elsewhere. What searchterm do I need to use to find one ?